# how do I integrate hosebird client library to a Grails project?

Tags: grails, dependency-management, twitter-hbc

My goal is to use the [hosebird client](https://github.com/twitter/hbc) provided by Twitter to stream tweets in my Grails project.

I'm really not sure how I will approach this, but I first tried including it in the dependencies in my BuildConfig.groovy like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.twitter:hbc-core:2.2.0'
}
```

And then, when I tried to mimic the example code, [FilterStreamExample.java](https://github.com/twitter/hbc/blob/master/hbc-example/src/main/java/com/twitter/hbc/example/FilterStreamExample.java), in my `TwitterService.groovy`, GGTS (the IDE) just shows me errors as I write these lines of code:

```
import com.google.common.collect.Lists
import com.twitter.hbc.ClientBuilder
import com.twitter.hbc.core.Client
import com.twitter.hbc.core.Constants
import com.twitter.hbc.core.endpoint.StatusesFilterEndpoint
import com.twitter.hbc.core.processor.StringDelimitedProcessor
import com.twitter.hbc.httpclient.auth.Authentication
import com.twitter.hbc.httpclient.auth.OAuth1
```

Obviously, this makes me unable to run the code because of the compile time error. It just tells that the error is something "Groovy was unable to resolve".

Can you tell what am I missing?

Is it just a groovy syntax error that I'm not noticing? I'm new to Groovy so please bear with me.

OR

Is the problem here is in the inclusion of the library in the dependencies?

My first aim is to be able to use the library this way as I have told it above (the BuildConfig way) **before** trying to make jars and put it in the src/java. Who knows, the compile time error will appear too. I just want to know if the current obstacle in the approach I did is easy to fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GGTS and STS don't parse `BuildConfig.groovy` - they get all classpath information from Grails. When you update `BuildConfig.groovy` with a new plugin or jar dependency, right-click on the project node in the tree on the left and select `Grails Tools` | `Refresh Dependencies` and GGTS will rebuild its classpath based on the current state of the app.

Comment: thank you for the response. I tried refreshing the dependencies and it disappear. 

Just a quick question...

Whenever I include something on the dependencies, do I really need to always refresh it like this? Is it not automatically loaded when I "grails run-app" the project?

Comment: That will cause Grails to update, but STS/GGTS won't be aware of it. Even if you run Grails from inside the IDE, or run tests, a script, a wizard, etc., all the IDE is doing is starting a process in a new JVM and capturing the output. In some cases it does a bit more, e.g. it uses test listeners to update the JUnit view for tests, and it updates its dependencies as I've described. But in general it's just running a process and capturing output.

Comment: alright. I guess i must rely with care on GGTS when using Grails. Even if one can do Grails with comfort even without an IDE, it's just that I started learning and using the framework using the IDE. 

Anyway, thank you.